# Progress dialog not getting dismissed

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I want a progress dialog saying "Please Wait" , while my code downloads and parses a xml file but the Progress Dialog is not going, it somehow getting stuck.
I am using AsyncTask, downloading of xml file and parsing are done in the background thread, the code is working if i remove the progress dialog, but in that case you have to wait for about 4 sec to click my button that dynamically creates UI.

```
private class ParseXML extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Document>{

private Context context;
    private Activity activity;
    private ProgressDialog pd;
    public ParseXML(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        context = activity;
        pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
    }




    public void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
    /*  ProgressDialog pd=ProgressDialog.show(XML_PARSER.this,"","Please Wait");*/

    }


    @Override
protected Document doInBackground(Integer... params) {

     DocumentBuilderFactory dbf= DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    Document dom1=null;
    try {

        //InputStream is=getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.options);
        URL requestURL = new URL("my url");
        URLConnection connection = requestURL.openConnection();
        is = connection.getInputStream();


        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        dom1=db.parse(is);
        Log.i(TAG,"parsing done");

    }

    catch(ParserConfigurationException pce){
        pce.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(SAXException se){
        se.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }


    ParseDocument(dom1); 



    return null;
    }           

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Document d){
        if(pd!=null && pd.isShowing()){
               pd.dismiss();
               }
        super.onPostExecute(d);

    }
}
```

Comment: whats your problem? what you want exactly? Do you want to dismiss the progress dialog?

Comment: @nick- got my solution. btw i needed to dismiss the progress dialog in my postExecute(). Now it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making mistake here

```
 public void onPreExecute(){
  super.onPreExecute();
 /*  ProgressDialog pd=ProgressDialog.show(XML_PARSER.this,"","Please Wait");*/
  }
```

you are declaring `ProgressDialog pd` a local variable

and when control is coming to

```
@Override
    public void onPostExecute(Document d){
        if(pd!=null && pd.isShowing()){
               pd.dismiss();
               }
        super.onPostExecute(d);

    }
```

pd is null here as you have not initialize the global pd variable. that is why alert dialog is not being dismissed.

to make this work just make some changes in `onPreExecute`

```
public void onPreExecute(){
      super.onPreExecute();
       pd=ProgressDialog.show(XML_PARSER.this,"","Please Wait");
      }
```

Comment: oh got it, beginners mistake. Let me try .

Comment: sorry for the late mark, i had some work that is why i was late and i know how to accept :P

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Its always advisable to keep the UI work on UI thread, and Non-UI work on Non-UI thread, but from Android version HoneyComb it became a rule.

**2.** So as you are using `AsyncTask`, let you `ProgressDialog` **start showing in the Dedicated UI thread**, from the `onCreate()` method.

**3.** Then **dismiss the** `ProgressDialog` from `onPostExecute()` Method, which is again on the Dedicated UI thread.

Comment: ok, but will it matter where i am starting my progress dialog? , because it is starting but is not closing.

Comment: Thats what i am saying, start it from the onCreate, and put the dismiss() in the onPostExecute() method, that will lead to the termination of the Dialog...and yes..if you Progress Dialog is starting...there is no need to check of null etc in the onPostExecute()